# Error: Function call missing argument list

Tags: c++, function

I am getting this error when I compile my program, but I don't see anything wrong with the code.

> Error 1   error C3867: 'President::getFirstName': function call missing argument list; use '&President::getFirstName' to create a pointer to member   h:\president_folder\president_folder\president_driver.cpp   95  1   president_folder

I'm not sure how to interpret it.

```
    //outputData function
void outputData(President prez_array[],fstream &outFile, int count)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        outFile << prez_array[i].getFirstName << endl;
        outFile << prez_array[i].getLastName << endl;
        outFile << prez_array[i].getBeginYear << endl;
        outFile << prez_array[i].getEndYear << endl;
        outFile << prez_array[i].getPartyAffil << endl;
        outFile << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need add parentheses to your functions, e.g. `outFile << prez_array[i].getFirstName() << endl;`.

Comment: Can you add the definition of `President`? Also, the error says `getFirstName` is a function but your treating it like a member variable in your code.

Comment: If you're getting that error when you compile, then the title of your question is wrong; it says *function call compiles*, which clearly it doesn't. We have no idea what `prez_array` is, because we don't know what `President` is that it conains. If you want help here, be clear about what you're asking and provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

it looks that you forget how to call a function:

```
outFile << prez_array[i].getFirstName() << endl;
outFile << prez_array[i].getLastName() << endl;
outFile << prez_array[i].getBeginYear() << endl;
outFile << prez_array[i].getEndYear() << endl;
outFile << prez_array[i].getPartyAffil() << endl;
```